# Title Styling Error Mobile App Development

Tags: react-native

I'm having some trouble with styling my react-native mobile application. This is how I styled everything:

```
return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.headingText}>
            Penn<Text style={styles.buzzText}>Buzz</Text>
      </Text>
        <View style={styles.inputView}>
            <TextInput
                style={styles.inputText}
                placeholder="Username"
                placeholderTextColor="white"
                onChangeText={handleUsernameChange}/>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.inputView}>
            <TextInput
                style={styles.inputText}
                secureTextEntry
                placeholder="Password"
                placeholderTextColor="white"
                onChangeText={handlePasswordChange}/>
        </View>
        {errorMessage != '' ? (
              <Text style={styles.errorStyle}>
                {errorMessage}
              </Text>
        ) : null}
        <TouchableOpacity
            onPress = {handleSubmit}
            style={styles.loginBtn}>
            <Text style={styles.loginText}>Sign In </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    },

    headingText: {
        fontSize: 36,
        fontWeight: "bold",
        marginBottom: 30,
    },
    
    buzzText: {
        color: "#F8C53A",
    },
    
    inputView:{
        width:"80%",
        backgroundColor:"#3AB4BA",
        borderRadius:25,
        height:50,
        marginBottom:20,
        marginTop: 20,
        justifyContent:"center",
        padding:20
    },
    
    inputText:{
        height:50,
        fontSize: 19,
        color:"white"
    },
        
    loginBtn:{
        width:"80%",
        backgroundColor:"#fb5b5a",
        borderRadius:25,
        height:50,
        alignItems:"center",
        justifyContent:"center",
        marginTop:40,
        marginBottom:10
    },

    loginText: {
        height: 25,
        color: "white",
        fontWeight: "bold",
        fontSize: 19
    },

    errorStyle: {
        color: "black",
        fontSize: 19
    }
});
```

Right now when I render my application, all the elements are pushed to the top of the screen. Additionally, the heading/buzztext for "PennBuzz" do not appear on the screen no matter what. I've tried changing the text color multiple times, but it just doesn't render. Any ideas on how to fix this?

This is the current output: [current rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qwtw.png) I'm not sure how to get the elements to be pushed down and also for the title to show up.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use instead of a **View** the **SafeAreaView**

```bash
{/*old*/}
<View style={styles.container}>
...
</View>

{/*new*/}
<SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
...
</SafeAreaView>
```

That is because on iOS and some Android devices have Notch space.
On the other hand, if you plan to have a full screen like an Onboarding or something like that, you should be ok with the standard View.

Just a tip if you plan to use navigation, this lib has its implementation of the **SafeAreaView** just remember to look at imports for more info [link](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/handling-safe-area/)

I hope this help you.